# How to protect against Encoded URL XSS Attack

Tags: javascript, php, html, security, xss

I got following 2 questions as:

**1) How to protect from this kind of XSS Attacks?**

https://www.example.com/index.php?&#0000106&#0000097&#0000118&#0000097&#0000115&#0000099&#0000114&#0000105&#0000112&#0000116&#0000058&#0000097&#0000108&#0000101&#0000114&#0000116&#0000040&#0000039&#0000088&#0000083&#0000083&#0000039&#0000041

If suppose for some reason, the query parameter is embedded in an image load event then it would be like this

```
<img src=x onload="&#0000106&#0000097&#0000118&#0000097&#0000115&#0000099&#0000114&#0000105&#0000112&#0000116&#0000058&#0000097&#0000108&#0000101&#0000114&#0000116&#0000040&#0000039&#0000088&#0000083&#0000083&#0000039&#0000041">

//And browser treats as
<img src=x onload="javascript:alert('XSS')">
```

I am already using PHP's `htmlspecialchars()` and `Filtar_var()` with URL Sanitization, but this kind of encoded XSS will easily get pass through these functions

*How can we defend such Encoded XSS or neutralize any such attack?*

**2) Is it necessary for an XSS attack to get embedded in HTML Page, Javascript or CSS etc in order to get triggered? or there can be a way where XSS does not need to be embedded?**

Comment: Please state the reason for down voting so I can correct my problem. I have tried my level best and only asked this because I seek some expertise from experts. Thanks. If it is a duplicate question then point me to that because I could not find one.

Comment: XSS attack prevention is both very easy and also very hard. It's very easy, because you don't need to filter all sorts of things - just avoid directly using untrusted data. It's also hard to identify what the untrusted data is in order to prevent it. In your example, you have a script tag encouded as URL. If you never take the URL, decode it, and insert it in the HTML raw, then you would not trigger the attack.

Comment: @VLAZ thanks for reply. The above encoded URL is an input from my user and he tried to XSS attack my website. My Rules could not detect it and bypassed. I want to know what should I do to mitigate this kind of XSS attack. I want to allow my users to provide any link in comments. As this is a input from a user into a comment page

Answer (score 1):

`htmlspecialchars` is a perfectly good defence against XSS when you are inserting user input into an HTML document.

It stops any HTML syntax in the user input from breaking out of where you intend for it to go and being treated as JavaScript.

Your problem has nothing to do with the fact the attack is encoded. The problem is that are are putting user input somewhere that JavaScript is expected (and `onload` attribute) so it is **already being treated as JavaScript**.

`json_encode` is the *usual* solution here (and *then* `htmlspecialchars` because the JavaScript is inside an HTML attribute).

However, that only works when you are taking user input and putting it into a script to be used as data. Here it seems that you are taking user input and just treating the whole thing as a JavaScript function.

If you do that then you are going to be vulnerable to XSS. You can mitigate it to some degree by implementing defenses against CSRF, but you almost certainly shouldn't be doing this in the first place.

Comment: Thanks Quentin for understanding my concerns. So, you mean to say that I am just fine as long as I am properly using htmlspecialchars and not putting user input in any event handler of javascript?

Comment: There are some other places which are unsafe by default (such as some attributes which accept URLs) and you can always make yourself vulnerable by using JS to read the attribute value and then processing it in certain ways (`eval` being an obvious case).

Comment: Ok so my only last question is that if every user input is passed through `htmlspecialchars` and placed only inside <p> or <div> tags not in anywhere else like attributes or called by some javascript `eval` functions, then I am perfectly fine? right?

Comment: I tried to do my homework you can see at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60578652/proper-implementation-for-the-protection-against-xss-attack but only this encoding question was bothering me

Comment: There's no technical attack that could be implemented that way. It's possible that a message written in plain english could be injected which would trick a user into doing something harmful.